Path integrals, instantons and triple well potential
I've got a question about instantons in a triple well potential. I'm following Coleman's discussion in 'Aspects of symmetry' and am trying to work out the lowest energy eigenvalues in respect to a triple well potential. I have assumed that the potential $V(x)$ is symmetric ($V(x) = V(-x)$), that it has three minima at $x=0,\pm a$, and that $V''(0) = V''(\pm a) = \omega^2$. In a similar fashion to what was found for the double well potential $$
K(x_f;x_i) = (\frac{\omega}{\pi \hbar})^{1/2}e^{-\omega T/2}\sum_{certain-n}
\frac{(ke^{-S_0/\hbar}T)^n}{n!}
$$
where $k$ is defined as to give the correct answer for a single instanton solution and $S_0$ is the action for a single instanton. Now the task is to find appropriate conditions for the number $n$ of instantons and anti-instantons, in respect to $x_f$ and $x_i$. What i found is:

for $x_f = -a$ and $x_i = a$, $n$ must be even and $n \geq 2$; thus the infinite sum becomes $cosh(ke^{-S_0 /\hbar}T) - 1$. This means that there are three low eigenvalues: $E' =\hbar \omega/2,E_\pm = \hbar \omega/2 \pm \hbar k e^{-S_0/\hbar} $; and three eigenstates: $|E'\rangle, |E_\pm \rangle$. Moreover $\langle -a| E'\rangle \langle E'| a\rangle \neq 0 $.
for $x_i=x_f = \pm a$, $n$ must only be even, so the infinite sum is $cosh(ke^{-S_0 /\hbar}T)$. From this we find only the $E_\pm$ eigenvalues. This must mean that $| \langle \pm a | E' \rangle |^2 = 0$. And we arrive at a contradiction.
So what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance to anyone who's kind enough to help me.

